# Why does create() in PayPal's batch payments via API return False?

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#payouts_create

Sample code:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payout/create.py

Why does `create()` return False? How do I get an explanation of why?

Update: I was able to get this info, but it's not helpful either:

```
ForbiddenAccess: Failed. Response status: 403. Response message: Forbidden. Error message: {"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred","debug_id":"60e73559274d3","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#AUTHORIZATION_ERROR"}
```

Answer (score 7):

PayPal tech/dev support told me the debug ID said I didn't have Mass Pay enabled on my account, so I had to call them and talk to general support. I did, and they said they cannot enable it on Canadian accounts. I'm going to have to change payment processors to someone who offers the Mass Pay feature. I need to send out 500 micro payments to 500 different people.

They told me to open a US PayPal account. They asked if I had a US residence, and I do have a vacation home in the US. Then they asked me if I had a social security number, and I don't. So that option was not available.

Update: I told PayPal technical support that it could not be enabled in Canada. They told me that it works in Canada on the sandbox, so maybe it's coming soon. However, they said there is a feature called [Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/?mark=payouts) that can work for me. They went ahead and enabled it for me. So I'm going with that instead of mass pay.

Moral of the story: PayPal technical support via email sorted it all out. Their phone support is useless and stubborn.

Answer (score 1):

The error message pretty clearly says that an authorization error occurred.  Without any further information the only thing I can assume is that you either did not include an OAuth bearer token in the request, or the token was invalid (although I believe an invalid or expired token will return HTTP 401, not 403).

See [Make your first call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) or [How PayPal uses OAuth 2.0](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/) for a high level overview

You might be able to get a more definitive answer if you post the request information that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this as well on payouts, and found following fix on [PayPal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#error-AUTHORIZATION_ERROR)

> **AUTHORIZATION_ERROR** Your account is not authorized to use payouts. Contact your account manager or our customer service team for
>   assistance. Your account is not authorized to use payouts. For
>   assistance, contact your account manager or our customer service team.